# Coldfusion XML Character encoding

Tags: xml, coldfusion, character-encoding

I make a soap webservices call with coldfusion and get back a UTF-8 encoded response and save it as an xml file.

```
<cfset a = createObject("webservice","https://somesite/service?wsdl")/>
<cfset b = a.getObject("Param1","Param2","Param3","ObjectName")/>
<cfset c = b.getXml()/>
<cffile action="write" file="#ExpandPath('./result.xml')#" output="#c#"/>
```

When I open the file in a text editor i see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>
        <report_row>
        ...
        <c43>... an â€œexperimentalâ€? ...</c43>
        ...
        </report_row>
</report>
```

instead of  “experimental” and when I try to open it with a browser I get encoding errors.

How do I get the data in right format/encoding?

Comment: are you sure that what you are getting from the web service is UTF-8?

Comment: @ryber not sure. How can I check?

Comment: @KobbyPemson, if you navigate in your browser to the WSDL and then view the source you should see the charset.

Comment: @Dave it is UTF-8 and there is a comment in the wsdl <!-- 
WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Jun 07, 2006 (10:40:03 PDT)

  -->

Comment: So now you know that you are dealing with UTF-8.  I would suggest pull the WSDL into something like SOAP-UI and checking the content directly outside of ColdFusion.

Comment: @Dave i tried SoapUI but it didn't like the wsdl. Java Null pointer errors

Answer (score 1):

See in the database or what ever file from which you are getting this 'experimental'. There may be something of an extra character lurking there like special quote symbol.

Comment: The user typed it in ms word then did a copy and paste into this webapp. The only way to get information from the webapp is via soap. It looks normal in the app.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look in the app, if possible, and seeing what they do to the content to remove any extra formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `charset="utf-8"` to your `<cffile />` tag. More information in the [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_11.html).

Comment: Tried it but got Ã¢â‚¬Å“experimentalÃ¢â‚¬ï¿½ instead

Comment: I believe that UTF-8 is the default

Comment: @ryber, UTF-8 is only default if JRun (or the J2EE server) is set to UTF-8.  According to the livedocs charset defaults to the J2EE charset.